# CSS issue about spacing between a select box and text box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to work on the spacing between fields on a particular line.  It seems like I have figure out the space between text boxes with the `margin-right` property.

I am trying to put the same number of spaces between a select option box and a text box and it doesn’t seem to work.    Is there a different margin property for select boxes than textboxes?

Here are my CSS classes and my HTML code for the select option box:

```
.textsmall {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.combosmall [
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```
input id="CMDContractYear" type="number" class="textsmall" maxlength="4" 

select size="1" name="CMDSchedStatus" class="combosmall" 

input id="CMDCreationDate" type="text" class="textsmall" maxlength="10"
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a square bracket `[` instead of a curly bracket `{` for `.combosmall`. It would also help if you included the actual HTML and not the _"pseudo HTML"_ you have provided.

Comment: Uhhh should have seen that.   Thanks

Comment: Did that fix the issue or is there still a problem?

Comment: If the problem really was the errant `[` in your CSS code then you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) one of the answers below. If you make the effort to accept answers it will be more likely that other people will take the trouble to help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you put a "[" when you meant to put a "{" in your combosmall css.
Change

```
.combosmall[display:inline-block; margin-right:25px; }
```

To

```
.combosmall{display:inline-block; margin-right:25px; }
```

It happens...

Answer (score 1):

You have a square bracket `[` instead of a curly bracket `{` for `.combosmall`.